# Post request sending undefined when sent as form-data

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I've got an express app set up.

I have defined my routes,

```
var ctrlLocations = require('../controllers/locations');
router.post('/locations', ctrlLocations.locationsCreate);
module.exports = router;
```

And here is the locations.js file,

```
module.exports.locationsCreate = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.name);
}
```

When I send a post request using Postman, if I send the body as a x-www-form-urlencoded, everything works fine and I see the 'name' as I had defined it.

However, when I send the post request with the body as form-data, I get 'undefined'

Yes, I'm using body-parser

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Comment: Can you add your form code? How and on what url you're submitting your form.

Comment: Set `extended: false` in `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending multipart/form-data, you have to use a middleware that supports that `Content-Type`. `body-parser` does not support this. You should use a module like `multer` for multipart/form-data support.